# <br> between two variables in javascript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, string, line-breaks

I create with php, a  JavaScript file where inside there are two variables.

I want that two variables are on two different lines, maybe using a tag

The problem is that the output on the browser works, but inside the file.js the two variables are on the same line, and between a variable and the other there is 
 (in text)

```
$javascriptContent = json_encode($var);
$settimana = "hello";
$javascriptContent = 'var settimana= "'. $settimana .'"; <br>  var reports = '. $javascriptContent . ";";
file_put_contents($path, $javascriptContent);
```

works only on browser in the file no

I tried also with:

```
<br />
\n
```

nut nothing :(

Comment: Escape sequences only work in double quoted strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have HTML tags.  It just has JavaScript code.  What you're looking for is a newline character, not an HTML tag.  Something like this:

```
'var settimana= "' . $settimana . '";' . "\r\n" . 'var reports = '. $javascriptContent . ";"
```

(Note the use of a double-quoted string to interpret the newline, as a single-quoted string won't interpret it and just treat those as literal characters.)

Comment: simple and effective answer, if you can (just curious) if I wanted to have the same effect for output to the browser what should I do? because with your code works in file.js (I needed to), but does not work on the browser

Comment: @Giovanni-Borgia: What do you mean "does not work on the browser"?  If you mean that in HTML you don't see the new line then that's because browsers don't render whitespace as markup.  In HTML you'd likely want to use a `<br />` tag.

Comment: I print the contents of the file with "print", with your code (rightly) the printout is all on one line. But in file.js it is on two lines (as I wanted). Putting <br>, when I print the content, it is located on two different lines (but not in file.js and also is reported <br> as text). I was wondering if there was a way to have both results ... :) but if it's too complicated or not you understand me do not worry :)

Comment: @Giovanni-Borgia: Well, HTML and JavaScript are two different things.  You *can* emit a newline character to HTML exactly as I do in this answer for JavaScript.  That newline character will be there in the page source.  But browser's don't render that as a line break because that's not how HTML works.  Similarly you *can* emit a `<br />` to JavaScript as you already did, but `<br />` isn't valid JavaScript code so that would be a syntax error.  There's no single solution for two *vastly* different languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `\n` inside single-quoted strings in PHP to form newlines. Escape the double quotes instead:

```
$javascriptContent = 'var settimana= "'. $settimana ."\";\nvar reports = ". $javascriptContent . ";";
```